# What does ip_summed exactly mean in skb?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, kernel

The sk_buff has a member ip_summed commented with

> @ip_summed: Driver fed us an IP checksum

It seems to indicate the checksum status of **IP/L3** layer from its name.
But according to it's possible value such as:

> CHECKSUM_UNNECESSARY
> The hardware you’re dealing with doesn’t calculate the full checksum (as in CHECKSUM_COMPLETE), but it does parse headers and verify checksums for specific protocols. For such packets it will set CHECKSUM_UNNECESSARY if their checksums are okay. sk_buff.csum is still undefined in this case though. A driver or device must never modify the checksum field in the packet even if checksum is verified.
> CHECKSUM_UNNECESSARY is applicable to following protocols:
> TCP: IPv6 and IPv4.
> UDP: IPv4 and IPv6. A device may apply CHECKSUM_UNNECESSARY to a zero UDP checksum for either IPv4 or IPv6, the networking stack may perform further validation in this case.
> GRE: only if the checksum is present in the header.
> SCTP: indicates the CRC in SCTP header has been validated.
> FCOE: indicates the CRC in FC frame has been validated.

in https://docs.kernel.org/networking/skbuff.html it seems to indicate the checksum status of **L4** layer.

Besides, in ip_rcv() it seems the ip_summed is not used before calculating the checksum of IP header.
So is there any reason the member is named as **ip**_summed rather than **l4**_summed (maybe)?

Answer (score 0):

We believe this was added as an optimization to skip computing and
verifying checksums for communication between containers. However, locally
generated packets have ip_summed == CHECKSUM_PARTIAL, so the code as
written does nothing for them. As far as we can tell, after removing this
code, these packets are transmitted from one stack to another unmodified
(tcpdump shows invalid checksums on both sides, as expected), and they are
delivered correctly to applications. We didn’t test every possible network
configuration, but we tried a few common ones such as bridging containers,
using NAT between the host and a container, and routing from hardware
devices to containers. We have effectively deployed this in production at
Twitter (by disabling RX checksum offloading on veth devices).

```
if (skb->ip_summed == CHECKSUM_COMPLETE)
    skb->csum = csum_block_sub(skb->csum,
                   csum_partial(start, len, 0), off);
else if (skb->ip_summed == CHECKSUM_PARTIAL &&
     skb_checksum_start_offset(skb) < 0)
    skb->ip_summed = CHECKSUM_NONE;
```

Comment: Your post seems to be something about veth driver and I don't think it solved my question. Thanks for posting though.